# Sort function that accepts strings or numbers

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to modify some code I found for a table that allows sorting on its columns. The example only worked on string values, I'm trying to modify it so that my table can contain numbers in some of the columns and still keep the sorting function. The example I'm working from can be found here https://github.com/mantinedev/ui.mantine.dev/blob/master/lib/TableSort/TableSort.tsx

This is the sort function I'm currently working with. I've tried using if statements and typeof to change how I'm sorting, but I'm fairly new to typescript and can't seem to figure it out.

```
function sortData(
data: dataInterface[],
payload: { sortBy: keyof dataInterface | null; reversed: boolean; search: string }) {
const { sortBy } = payload;

if (!sortBy) {
    return filterData(data, payload.search);
}

return filterData(
    [...data].sort((a, b) => {
        if (payload.reversed) {
                return b[sortBy].localeCompare(a[sortBy]);
        }

        return a[sortBy].localeCompare(b[sortBy]);
    }),
    payload.search
);
}
```

FilterData function:

```
function filterData(data: dataInterface[], search: string) {
const query = search.toLowerCase().trim();
return data.filter((item) =>
    keys(data[0]).some((key) => item[key].toLowerCase().includes(query))
);
}
```

my dataInterface looks like this:

```
interface dataInterface {
guid: string;
name: string;
set: string;
quantity: string;
price: number;
}
```

Comment: How does the sort function know if it should sort a column as string or as number? At runtime, the code has no type information.

Comment: Please [edit] the example code to be a [mre] without unrelated problems like use of an external or private `filterData()`.  We should be able to copy and paste this into our own IDEs and immediately get to work on it without first having to debug issues you're not asking about.

Comment: I've included the fiterData() function, my apologies!

Comment:  But now you're using `keys`.  Could you try your code out in a standalone IDE to make sure it's a [mre]?  Ideally you'd *remove* things instead of supplying them.  We don't really need to worry about filtering if you're just asking about sorting, right? ... For instance, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOroMW) is one way to do the sorting, and I've removed all your `filter` stuff since I presume you could figure that part out offline. Does that make sense?

Comment: My apologies again, I posted half asleep before bed, and again after waking up. I shouldn't be asking questions before my coffee... My bad. I completely missed the keys reference, it's defined in @mantine/core. I copy pasted the example and don't have a good understanding of how it works yet, I probably should have started there before trying to modify it. Your example makes sense though, I'll play with this after work and see if I can get something running. Thanks for your help and patience :)

Comment: If it does work for you I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining it; let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: I was able to get it to work over my lunch break based on your example above, thank you so much! If you want to write up an answer I'll select it as the correct answer. I really like that approach, it's so much simpler than I was making it out to be in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom comparator (the type of callback that [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) expects) that accepts values of either `string` or `number`.

If both inputs are `string`s then you use your existing [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) approach, which behaves like `(a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)`.  If both inputs are `number`s then you use the standard numeric `(a, b) => a - b`.

The only wrinkle is deciding what to do if one input is a `number` and the other is a `string`.  In practice this should not happen given your definitions.  If you really wanted you could go through the fairly painful exercise of having TypeScript understand this, but that's too much work for almost no benefit.  An easier approach is just to choose some reasonable behavior in such an unexpected situation.  By "reasonable" I mean that you do something simple that does not break the rules for comparators (i.e., comparators must be pure stable, reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive; see the [MDN docs for `sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) for details)

For example, you could just have all `string`s come before all `number`s.  That gives us this comparator:

```
const strOrNumCmp = (a: string | number, b: string | number) =>
  (typeof a === "string") ?
    (typeof b === "string") ? a.localeCompare(b) : -1 :
    (typeof b === "string") ? 1 : a - b;

const v: (string | number)[] = [1, "x", 2, "y", 0, "a", -1, "b"];
v.sort(strOrNumCmp);
console.log(v);
// ["a", "b", "x", "y", -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Looks reasonable.  Again, it really doesn't matter what you do as long as it's consistent.

---

Anyway, then you can write `sortData()` to call `strOrNumCp` on `a[key]` and `b[key]`, like:

```
function sortData(data: DataInterface[], key: keyof DataInterface) {
  return data.sort((a, b) => strOrNumCmp(a[key], b[key]));
}
```

although of course you could customize it as you need (conditionally reversing the order, filtering, etc).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 2):

For sorting values based on number and string both; you can first check the type of the values in the columns, and then perform the appropriate comparison operation based on the data type(for string I used ***[`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)***). Something like:

```js
function sortData(
  data: dataInterface[],
  payload: { sortBy: keyof dataInterface | null; reversed: boolean; search: string }
) {
  const { sortBy } = payload;

  if (!sortBy) {
    return filterData(data, payload.search);
  }

  return filterData(
    [...data].sort((a, b) => {
      // Check if the values are numbers or strings
      const isNumber = typeof a[sortBy] === 'number' && typeof b[sortBy] === 'number';
      const isString = typeof a[sortBy] === 'string' && typeof b[sortBy] === 'string';

      let result = 0;

      // Perform the appropriate comparison based on the data type
      if (isNumber) {
        result = (a[sortBy] as number) - (b[sortBy] as number);
      } else if (isString) {
        result = (a[sortBy] as string).localeCompare(b[sortBy] as string);
      }

      // Reverse the result if necessary
      return payload.reversed ? -result : result;
    }),
    payload.search
  );
}
```

***[TYPESCRIPT PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCZzHAkua8nIDeAUMsgOYCuwqAXMgM5hSjkDcpyIcAthPUxYh2nBhDADmrDmQCOlOOGBgAnpKEiyABxZJ6ISjwBG0DgF9ixBAHsQTNBjj10mHJFiIIAbQC6yALzIXpwkZGRUNPQARACMUQA0nGTcfNEAClDWqJQIYMgAgglJjOLRAMriyHGJYcjyimDKashRAKxFtTrAelUADL01yGaDoWERdC0ATB1hKfwtGVk5eQBCM2RiEi0VedODcgpKqtExvevIXT2T-YPDIcXj0QDM53Ppmdm5yADC55vllRe+zqh0axxaMXawMu8yeN04dx8HGIMEoIFywFsyBgwAANu4ACKOAAULicDlcuA8SF88RKcCgCAAFupWABKIicAD0XOQWB4WlxED44GQKmslCg2Lx7lYyFx1nI3WQTOgEE4UHEkpAFLg5ksqPRjSxDGsUDARMwxM4ZOcjjceE8tM4WjgKgVcAmhEYZrAK2aAGsIOKYLqHdSUAAfLiUXG4tjITUAN2gYgmRms1iFigTYgZzNZwiGxA5oxsdjy3tN5v9QwCFzdHtQyLIwFDxIAhNW-SpS8VNWBtdL8dBLXBSY46a73dZPQA6POMplsmTFjVaqA6nEjqBj621Lxzo9knwL33E4lwOlGDn+AB8nNqZB5P1VCADyDbyDAquQSbguKUBADDIAyKAGMYqbIGajBSMIDDFGQ5b2MADAAHKGCYUqBKoWgQNYoZwF43b+n4-jkS0EFYVEyAAGS0d+Kh4QRyBGMRvqkQEFFRFR0BRKutTIXkqFlHB5D1rh+GEexNYqGR3GCKwNH0YxzGhmxJFyVxgRRIpwj8ZYT7ypUmoMLGeSBL0LZPi+aR4GaPDfr+cBaDo1hdBgKA2AKDKoViRhwGm0E6j+KBkqp6pGV+xKoRhkFQH2RlkKZ5n1peMk9n4gUxvFHIALTIMSGkcVp2W8QlAlhGYyAQLiYifu2IliYlSUpfiaVEZpWUgXp5BsnOCoIABEDfNYPmakVGWcdlvUroha5GS+ABKEAplA9WhYmwGpV+IAQEgDAMAyKjzQOQ7Tk2c7JqmECoMgAD8yB5W1eT0C9lVmGy0KNrOqALhA+ZMpwc0WMQL4ACrAXkm3dmO2JohithWLY9jdrdcOBLDJJknSVYldEMIJFta1pvQ8B1RAdKLgWLQ0Z9HDIVmEADYqxJo6gY4rkAA)***

Comment: Presumably you will never have `a[sortBy]` and `b[sortBy]` be of different types, but if that does happen, you are assuming they are equal, but that doesn't meet the guidelines for comparators according to [the `sort()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Comparators should be transitive, but `cmp(1, "a")` and `cmp("a", 2)` are both `0`, but `cmp(1, 2)` is not.  If you do have mixed types it could really do weird things to the resulting order. Maybe you should just have strings come before numbers or vice versa?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for pointing it out.  First I also do agree that `a[sortBy]` and `b[sortBy]` never be of different types. I can think of two ways to tackle the transitivity issue which you mentioned. 1. Use `localeCompare` with the numeric option set to true, which makes the function compare strings containing numbers correctly. It treats numbers in the strings as numerals rather than individual characters.
2.  Handling mixed types explicitly. Please correct me if I'm wrong and also which way you propose would be ok?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm going to try this out along with suggestions from another comment after work. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if `localeCompare` will work on two numbers if they are like `3.2` and `3.11`. Personally I'd just say something like "strings come before numbers".

Comment: @jcalz thanks for clarifying some doubts which I had initially. You're correct that method(i.e. Approach 1 mentioned in the earlier comment) will not work for the example that you gave. Says `3.2` comes before `3.11`